# IE forcing floating div to bottom despite fixed width container?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, positioning

I've been working on http://healthimpactnews.com and I need to fix this issue asap.

For some reason, IE, and IE only, squeezes the right-hand sidebar down below the other divs even though all the div columns are floating and within a fixed width container. My browsers create a horizontal scroll bar when the are sized down, but IE just forces the div down, instead.

Anyone know why?

Comment: IE8 seems to work fine =) IE8-compat doesn't indeed. It's always the same with IE8-compat/IE7 ;) I'll check what you can do about it.

Comment: I only see the default parking page by your service provider.  Can you post the html, css, and any js for this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div with class `ct_w` is `1000px` width;

The first child of that (`ct`) is also `1000px` width,

so it pushes the second child `ct_c3` (the right bar) away... (down)

**solution:**

completely remove the `width` property of the div with class `ct`

```
.ct {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1000px; /** <--- remove this **/
}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks much for that! I didn't think about the two div widths!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your container, "ct_w", has a width of 1000px; your left column, "ct" also has a width of 1000px. There is no room left there for your sidebar, "ct_c3". The other browsers are actually being nice by rendering the sidebar where it is. In fact, they're only doing that because you didn't clear your floats, so they don't understand the box model of ct_w.

Use a clearfix on ct_w, set the width of ct to 750px (or 749px for IE7), and make ct float left, then you will see the layout you're looking for.

Comment: I understand... thanks for the explanation. It's a premium theme, I didn't think it would have such issues. All is well now though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  the following:

```
.ct_w {
    ...
    float: left;
    width: 750px;
    ...
}

.ct_c3 {
   ...
   float: right;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work as well:

```
.ct
{
    float:left;
    width:750px;
}
```

And remove the margin part, because it is not needed when floating the toolbar next to it.